# Inline output using query_to_xml in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Running following query in postgresql

```
select REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                   query_to_xml(
                      'select 1 "col1",2 "col2",3 "col3"
                         union all
                         select 11 "col1",22 "col2",33 "col3"
                         union all
                         select 111 "col1",222 "col2",333 "col3"',
                      true,
                      false,
                      ''
                   )::text ,
                   '< row >',
                   '< Leaf >'
                ),
                '< /row >',
                '< /Leaf >'
             ),
             '< table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >',
             '< Tree >'
          ),
          '< /table >',
          '< /Tree >'
       )
```

Results in (multiple lines)

```
< Tree >

< Leaf >

< col1 >1< /col1 >

< col2 >2< /col2 >

< col3 >3< /col3 >

< /Leaf >

< Leaf >

< col1 >11< /col1 >

< col2 >22< /col2 >

< col3 >33< /col3 >

< /Leaf >

< Leaf >

< col1 >111< /col1 >

< col2 >222< /col2 >

< col3 >333< /col3 >

< /Leaf >

< /Tree >
```

Required in(i.e single line statement)

```
< Tree >  < Leaf >   < col1 >1< /col1 >   < col2 >2< /col2 >   < col3 >3< /col3 > < /Leaf >  < Leaf >   < col1 >11< /col1 >   < col2 >22< /col2 >   < col3 >33< /col3 > < /Leaf >  < Leaf >   < col1 >111< /col1 >   < col2 >222< /col2 >   < col3 >333< /col3 > < /Leaf >  < /Tree >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the newline character from the result. To remove new line you can use `regexp_replace(column_or_result, E'[\\n\\r]+', ' ', 'g' )`.

Your query should look like this:

> select regexp_replace(
>              REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(query_to_xml('select 1 "col1",2 "col2",3 "col3" union all select 11 "col1",22 "col2",33 "col3" union all select 111 "col1",222 "col2",333 "col3"',true,false,'')::text ,'< row >','< Leaf >') ,'< /row >','< /Leaf >') ,'< table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >','< Tree >') ,'< /table >','< /Tree >'),
>              E'[\n\r]+', ' ', 'g' )